# PropertyChanged is always fired

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, inotifypropertychanged, win-universal-app

I am using standard notification pattern with INotifyPropertyChanged. Here is my sample property:

```
private string fanart;
public string Fanart
{
    get { return fanart; }
    set
    {
        if (fanart != value)
        {
            fanart = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Fanart");
        }
    }
}
```

Here, I expect the setter to skip everything if new value is equal to the current value. However, when I check using debugger, `fanart` always equals `null` and consequently, the event is always fired. Any reason for the filed (and property) to be null?

Edit: This property is part of class called `PlayerItem`. `PlayerItem` is part of another class `PlayerState`. All these classes extend from `NotifyBase`. A method `RefreshPlayerState` periodically refreshes the `PlayerState`. I just noticed that new instance of `PlayerItem` is created every time player state is refreshed. What could be causing this?

Edit2: Creation of new instance is expected since I am deserializing the object from a JSON response. Now, how do I prevent setter from setting the value if older values are equal to values deserialized from the JSON? `myObj != value` will always return true since both are different objects although contained data is same.

This code is part of project [here](https://github.com/akshay2000/XBMCRemoteRT/blob/dev/XBMCRemoteRT/XBMCRemoteRT.Shared/Models/PlayerItem.cs). Feel free to look in for more details.

Comment: No problem in this code, any more details? How do you bind to it?

Comment: A very simple test would be `o.Fanart = "abc"; o.Fanart = "abc";` and seeing how often `PropertyChanged` is fired. You'll find that the event isn't raised twice in that case. My guess is that you're creating new instances of your class, and those new instances naturally don't have any default `Fanart` value.

Comment: The code you provided link for does not contain the `if(...)` statement.

Comment: Also, searched the project and found that you never set this property explicitly. Only deserialized.

Comment: @Grx70 Sorry about that. Fixed the link.
@MotiAzu I'm setting the parent composite object `PlayerItem` [here](https://github.com/akshay2000/XBMCRemoteRT/blob/dev/XBMCRemoteRT/XBMCRemoteRT.Shared/Helpers/PlayerHelper.cs).

Comment: @hvd You're correct. I added an empty constructor and set break point it it. New instance is being created. But why? How? Is there any way in Visual Studio to go back from a breakpoint and see what called the constructor?

Comment: @akshay2000 One of the debug windows is "Call stack", which should show you exactly what is calling your constructor.

Comment: @hvd Thanks. Checked! I'm desalinizing a JSON to `PlayerItem`. However, this gives fully backed object - not one with null fields. So, back to square one. If it is any help, the `PlayerState` is held as a static member. Does it matter?

Comment: @akshay2000 If I remember correctly, deserialization instantiates the object from a default constructor, then assigns the properties using reflection.  So on deserialization your property is going from null to value.

Comment: @SteveLillis Correct! That's expected behavior. And of course, the values are null since default constructor is used. Now, question is how to avoid setting values if the older ones are same as new ones? The earlier object and new object are different although contained values are same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"`fanart` always equals `null`" means most likely, you are recreating instances of the class that owns this field (which I assume is your *View Model*). You should keep the reference to your bound VM and work on that instance.

Edit: Currently I am working with a Windows 7 machine so I could not see your code. But you are removing those players somewhere; those that you create at `PlayerHelper` and `Player` classes.

Comment: Correct! I am deserializing from a JSON response. So, that's expected. Now, question is how do I make sure that setter doesn't set the values? Since older object is different from the new one, `myObj != value` will always return true.

Comment: @akshay2000 That's really up to your implementation, you might want to check all the properties etc... But your question was answered completely, you can mark it.